# Querying and returning distinct values & sum of quantities

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query in Symfony 2 where I am trying to return only unique values from a table with joins and the sum qty of those unique values.

For instance:

```
Inventory Table: 

id | product_id | qty  | warehouse_id
----------------------------------------
1  | 123        | 5    | 1
2  | 123        | 5    | 1
3  | 123        | 5    | 1
4  | 234        | 5    | 1 
5  | 345        | 5    | 1
6  | 345        | 5    | 1
7  | 345        | 5    | 1  
8  | 345        | 5    | 1  
9  | 345        | 5    | 1  
10 | 345        | 5    | 1  

Product Table: 

id   | name       | sku        | description    |
------------------------------------------------
123  | Test 123   | Test 123   | Test 123
234  | Test 234   | Test 234   | Test 234
345  | Test 345   | Test 345   | Test 345
```

So in the end, what I am needing in an array is pretty much following information plus what ever is coming back from the joins:

```
product_id: 123   qty: 15
product_id: 234   qty: 5
product_id: 345   qty: 30
```

Here is my full query... I am just not quite sure how to do this in Symfony 2 with the doctrine. Thanks for your help!

```
$search_string = trim($search_string);
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT    i, p, il, w
    FROM      WIC\InventoryBundle\Entity\Inventory i
    LEFT JOIN i.product p
    LEFT JOIN i.inventoryLocation il
    LEFT JOIN il.warehouse w
    WHERE     (p.name LIKE :tag OR p.sku LIKE :tag OR p.description LIKE :tag)
    AND       p.account = :account_id
    AND       il.warehouse = :location_id");
$query->setParameters(array(
    'tag'           => "%$search_string%",
    'account_id'    => $account_id,
    'location_id'    => $location_id
));
return $query->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$search_string = trim($search_string);
$q = $this->getEntityManager()
          ->getRepository('YourBundle:Inventory')
          ->createQueryBuilder('i');
$query = $q->select('SUM(DISTINCT(i.qty))')
    ->leftJoin('i.product', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('i.inventoryLocation', 'il')
    ->where($q->exp()->like('p.name', ':tag')
    ->orWhere($q->exp()->like('p.sku', ':tag')
    ->orWhere($q->exp()->like('p.description', ':tag')
    ->andWhere('p.account = :account_id')
    ->andWhere('il.warehouse = :location_id')
    ->setParameter('tag', $q->expr()->literal("%$search_string%"))
    ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id)
    ->setParameter('location_id', $location_id)
    ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

I did not what exactly your entity fieldnames are so correct them base on what you really have in your entity mapping